# How can I make a web scraper traverse multiple pages of search results using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, scripting, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a scraper to get results from the following page:

https://www.co.dutchess.ny.us/CountyClerkDocumentSearch/Search.aspx?q=nco1%253d2%2526name1%253da&page=1

I am trying to get all results, not just "A" results, but i figured I could start with one letter and then run through the whole alphabet. If someone can assist with this part that would be great too.

Anyway, I want to zero in on all Party Names, that is, elements with property class party-name.

I have the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://www.co.dutchess.ny.us/CountyClerkDocumentSearch/Search.aspx?q=nco1%253d2%2526name1%253da&page=1")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
nameList = bsObj.findAll("td", {"class":"party-name"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name.get_text())
```

However, this only works for one page. The results span over multiple pages. How can I accomplish this for multiple pages?

Also if you can help with getting all results, not just A, that would be great.

**EDIT**
I have improved my code now and can go over all searches. However, I still cannot go to the next page. I have tried using page_number++ but that does not know where to stop since number of page results varies. How could i have it go to the next page break at the last page???

New Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
for letter in all_letters:

    page_number = 1
    url = "https://www.co.dutchess.ny.us/CountyClerkDocumentSearch/Search.aspx?q=nco1%253d2%2526name1%253d" + letter + "&page=" + str (page_number)
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    nameList = bsObj.findAll("td", {"class":"party-name"})

    for name in nameList:
        print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: You could try using generators

Comment: Plase **don't repost questions**: [How to iterate through multiple results pages when web scraping with Beautiful Soup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407661/how-to-iterate-through-multiple-results-pages-when-web-scraping-with-beautiful-s)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to change the "starts_with" parameter on the page ans iterate over all the alphabets. If my understanding of the question is correct then this might be helpful.

If you analyze the url you will get your answer.

url = "https://www.co.dutchess.ny.us/CountyClerkDocumentSearch/Search.aspx?q=nco1%253d2%2526name1%253da&page=1"

the letter after "%253d" dictates the "starts_with" term. Currently it is 'a' hence it returns with starts with 'a' if you want to iterate just change the url

`url = 'https://www.co.dutchess.ny.us/CountyClerkDocumentSearch/Search.aspx?q=nco1%253d2%2526name1%253d' + starts_with + '&page=1'`

`starts_with` can be anything either a character (a,b,c,...) or a string (abc,asde,...)

Comment: I have updated my code ( please see updated code above ). I am now constructing my url as you have said and I am able to create a list of all possible beginnings of searches. So i have all searches covered now. However, I am unable to solve the next page part. I have tinkered with page_number++ but that goes up to infinity and wont stop. How can I limit it to the pages valid for each search result?

Answer (score -1):

I would solve it this way (pseudocode)

```
for letter in all_letters:
   page = 1
   while True:
       url = letter + page
       # scrape the page
       # check with bs if there is an a-element with id "NextLink1"
       if not link_to_next_page_found:
           break
       page += 1
```

Comment: I have updated my code ( please see updated code above ). I am now constructing my url as you have said and I am able to create a list of all possible beginnings of searches. So i have all searches covered now. However, I am unable to solve the next page part. I have tinkered with page_number++ but that goes up to infinity and wont stop. How can I limit it to the pages valid for each search result?